# How do I make a SQL Server replication?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, database-replication

I want to make one server a distributor for database replication.

The problem is that the SQL Server 2014 doesn't show me this option. It shows me only the option to create a subscription. I think it has to do with privileges on the server but I am the administrator. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What **edition** of SQL Server do you have? Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise? SQL Server **Express** can only be a subscriber in a replication .....

Comment: I have the SQL Management Studio 2014, don't remember the version of the installation. I tried to disconnect the server and after that, I show the option: Distribution but now I lost my Server. I have an Error by connection.

Comment: Run `SELECT @@VERSION` and post the results here - this will include the version and edition of your SQL Server

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) 
 Jun 10 2015 03:35:45 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 18362: )

Comment: So Express, I suppose I can't do it? Is there is a way thought?

Comment: As I said - Express can **only** be a subscriber - you **CANNOT** create a publisher for a replication with an Express edition.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks a lot for the info. I just upgraded the version and now I can see the option.

Comment: Read the Prerequisites section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-preparing-the-server-for-replication?view=sql-server-2017